# Disable browser back button in spring mvc application after logout

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I am doing spring mvc application in this when i logout from the application if i click browser back button its getting to the previous page of the application I have to restrict this and I tried this in my *.xml file

```
      <interceptors>
            <beans:bean id="webContentInterceptor"
              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
              <beans:property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
              <beans:property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true" />
              <beans:property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true" />
              <beans:property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true" />
            </beans:bean>
          </interceptors>
```

this is working only with in the application if I logout again if I click browser back button going to the previous page.

I tried with Javascript and Jquery examples but not working in my spring mvc application.
can any one please suggest me in this regard and approach to follow.

Comment: You should filter your request before proceed to `dispatcher-servlet`. In your filter, check if `HttpSession` exists or not, if not then back to login page. e.g `request.sendRedirect("login");`

Comment: @Nithin Please, check the link below if it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819660/page-not-secured-after-log-out-and-click-back-button

Comment: Hi Rahman can u please suggest with any simple example.

Comment: @Nithin see the example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Page not secured after log out and click back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819660/page-not-secured-after-log-out-and-click-back-button)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, Here I give you an idea with how you can do that.

Suppose you have a `SessionFilter` Class in package `com.test.filter` that implement `Filter`. Here you override the `doFilter()` method and checked that if session exist or not such like that:

```
public class SessionFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
                FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
                ServletException {

            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            String url = request.getRequestURI();
            
            response.setHeader("pragma", "no-cache");              
            response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");             
            response.setHeader("Expires", "0"); 
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            
            //!url.contains("login.html") check if the requested page is login page or not. you can do it a numerous way.
            // but for simpplicity here i do that
            if(session==null && !url.contains("login.html")) {
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.html"); // here goto http://yourdoamin/login.html
                response.setHeader("message", "Session Timeout."); // you can set your preferred message.
                return; //break filter chain, requested JSP/servlet will not be executed
            }
            
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
}
```

Now add the class reference in to `web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <description>session filter</description>
    <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.test.filter.SessionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Comment: Thank u for ur support, Hope with this I can solve my issue.

Comment: If that helps, then you can accept my answer and upvoted as it's SO's norm. :)