# Spring MVC IE7 redirect

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, internet-explorer-7

First, I execute `save.do` in `edit.jsp`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveUser.do")
public String saveUser(User user) {
    userService.save(user);
    return "redirect:/listUser.do";
}
```

I then system redirect to `list.do`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/listUser.do")
public String listUser(User user, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    List<User> list = userService.getAll(user, getRowBounds(request));
    request.setAttribute("list", list);
    return "/framework/system/user/listUser";
}
```

When I use chrome, the page will view new data.
But if I use IE7, the page does not view new data, only views the old data.
But with IE11 seems to be working fine.

Comment: IE7 doesn't clear cache automatically, you'll have to do that manually.

Comment: Tanks,I find answer.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364622/how-to-set-header-no-cache-in-spring-mvc-3-by-annotation

Answer (score 0):

Tanks for every one.
I find the answer.

Add

```html
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="webContentInterceptor" 
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
        <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

[how to set header no cache in spring mvc 3 by annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364622/how-to-set-header-no-cache-in-spring-mvc-3-by-annotation)