# allowing caching in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, xml-configuration

I want to allow caching for certain url. I added filter into `web.xml` and mapped it to url I am making requests to. My responses started to contain `etag` so I assumed it worked fine.

But default my responses from the server contains this headers.

[image]

But every time it returns code 200 every time instead of 304 (thus not using caching).

So I presumed its due to those headers it does not work properly.
I wanted to disabled those readers using `cache-control` tag.

[image]

But except `spring 4.0` that tag does not contain attribute `disabled`. 
So the question is - how to disabled it? (I am using `spring 3.1`)

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364622/how-to-set-header-no-cache-in-spring-mvc-3-by-annotation

Comment: I was trying to use but `spring-security` still add its `no-cache` headers. Maybe I'll be able to resolve it using filters or listeners somehow....Basically it's that https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2728. But I use even earlier version of spring...